# Python if statement scoping

Tags: python, python-3.x

On line 143-152 here: https://github.com/richardrl/improved-chainsaw/blob/master/gym_soccer/dqn.py

I noticed that, if I declare:

```
global q_values
```

in the `elif parameter_sharing and agent_id==0:` block, the next call to `q_values = q_func...` has the q_values variable scoped LOCALLY (q_values is found in locals() and not globals()) despite the "global q_values" line in the elif block. But if I declare global q_values outside of the elif block, the variable q_values is properly scoped to the global variable space.

Why is this happening and how do I properly set global-ness conditionally?

Comment: You can't set global-ness conditionally, and I don't understand why you would want to.

Comment: For this example, I have threads representing AI agents. I want these agents to have the ability to share variables or have their own local variables, aka to use global variables or use their own local variables. Is the only way to do this to copy a majority of the code into different files (a file with shared variables and a file without) and just edit the globalness of variables in each file? Seems like there should be a better way

Comment: Sounds like you want a class...

Comment: Python doesn't have block scoping, no. Only modules, functions, class bodies and comprehensions get a new scope.

Comment: If you have more complex scoping needs, consider using a class with instances, so you can distinguish between `self.[name]` and `[name]`.

Comment: I guess classes would work. But I have two types of variables that must be turned global or local like this. Therefore I would have 2^2 handwritten classes  and more with each additional variable I need the capability to change between global and local... I just googled dynamic class creation and found "metaclasses", I guess that is the solution?

Comment: I hardly ever use globals. Why do you need them?